# How to Align the code horizontally

Tags: html, css

How to make this align this horizontally, I am newbie, so dont give harsh comments please, I know css is used to align, but I dont know how to use css, I dont want spoon feeding,just explain me , how to edit  css of such type of codes

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="width:200px;height:900px;border:3px solid #000;"><div align="center"><a href=http://www.amazon.in/gp/goldbox/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&linkCode=ur2&tag=droiddevsin-21">
<font size="3" color="Blue">Products to buy</font></a><hr><center>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00OK305S0/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00OK305S0&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00OK305S0&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=droiddevsin-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00OK305S0"><br>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00OK305S0/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00OK305S0&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21">OnePlus One (16GB)</a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00OK305S0"><hr>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00GC1J55C/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00GC1J55C&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00GC1J55C&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=droiddevsin-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00GC1J55C"><br>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00GC1J55C/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00GC1J55C&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21">Google Nexus 5 D821 (16GB, Black)</a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00GC1J55C"><hr>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00VEB0F22/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00VEB0F22&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00VEB0F22&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=droiddevsin-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00VEB0F22"><br>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00VEB0F22/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00VEB0F22&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21">Mi 4 (White, 16GB)</a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00VEB0F22"><hr>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00E57TA50/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00E57TA50&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00E57TA50&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=droiddevsin-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00E57TA50"><br>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00E57TA50/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00E57TA50&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21">Sony Xperia Z Ultra (Black, 16GB)</a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00E57TA50"><hr>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00M6UC6LI/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00M6UC6LI&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21"><img border="0" src="http://ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B00M6UC6LI&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=droiddevsin-21" ></a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00M6UC6LI" ><br>
<a href="http://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00M6UC6LI/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=3626&creative=24822&creativeASIN=B00M6UC6LI&linkCode=as2&tag=droiddevsin-21">Google Nexus 9 Tablet (WiFi, 16GB), Lunar White</a><img src="http://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=droiddevsin-21&l=as2&o=31&a=B00M6UC6LI" >

</center></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your html is `img` inside your `a` tag or outside

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the margin of the first `div` element to `0 auto` with CSS, like so:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:200px;height:900px;border:3px solid #000;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="text-align:center;"` to the div tag (in which you need to align center)

Remove `<center>` tags

Comment: ..and `<font>` tags which are equally deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove tag `center` from your `HTML`

And than add

```
<style="text-align:center">
```